# UISplitViewController: How to prevent expansion when rotating from Compact to Regular

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitviewdelegate, uitraitcollection

There are many answers to the complementary question, which is how to prevent a transition to `PrimaryOverLay` on a from `Regular` to `Compact` interface change, eg use

```
func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
```

In my case, I have an iPhone 6+ with the detail view showing in portrait. When I rotate the device to horizontal (`Compact` to `Regular`), I want the primary view to stay hidden. I've tried setting the `preferredDisplayMode` to `.PrimaryHidden` in many places, but it has no apparent affect. Googling has turned up nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't override `traitCollection`, instead use the method `setOverrideTraitCollection:forChildViewController:` in a parent view controller of your split controller, like in Apple's example [AAPLTraitOverrideViewController.m](https://github.com/ios8/AdaptivePhotosAnAdaptiveApplication/blob/master/AdaptivePhotos/AAPLTraitOverrideViewController.m)

If your split controller doesn't have a parent, making a parent is really easy in the Storyboard. Add a new view controller, make it the entry point, add a container view, delete the default embedded view and instead add an embed segue to the split controller and set the override on `self.childViewControllers.firstObject` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Don’t believe storyboards existed when I wrote this, but agree, your suggestion better than subclassing.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after I wrote the question, but before posting it, I tripped on a [possible solution](http://coding.tabasoft.it/ios/the-new-uisplitviewcontroller/), which is to override the trait collection that the split view controller references.

I took that idea and decided to subclass `UISplitViewController`, and override the `traitCollection` property. That did the trick:

```
final class MySplitViewController: UISplitViewController {
  var didOnce = false
  override var traitCollection: UITraitCollection {
    let old = super.traitCollection
    let change = UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .Compact)
    let new = UITraitCollection(traitsFromCollections: [old, change])
    return new
  }
```

Obviously this is hardcoded for one device - later I'll go and add some functions that I can use to control what is in fact returned.